# VBA make if cell contains word insensitive

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to this but I was able to write my first code that actually accomplishes something useful. The purpose of the code is to open a spreadsheet extract values on a row given by name and copies it into master-spreadsheet and so on.

Unfortunately the code is not particularly robust when the the spacing where it is looking in the cell changes. Is there a way to change this "      Total Operating Expenses" to something like this: "*      Total Operating Expenses*" with the intent that the spacing does not matter only the word in the cell matters

```
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "      Total Operating Expenses" Then
        Range("B" & i, "M" & i).Copy
        TargetWb.Sheets("T-12 Drop").Range("E" & 9 + (k - 1) * 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

The whole code is listed below:

```
Sub ImportData()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWb As Workbook
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    
    'SourceWb - Workbook were data is copied from
    'TargetWb - Workbook were data is copied to and links are stored
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set TargetWb = Application.Workbooks("APC Refi Tracker.xlsm")
    Lastrow = Range("E100").End(xlUp).Row - 6

    
    For k = 1 To Lastrow
    
        filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("Import").Range("E" & 6 + k).Value
        Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
    Lastrow2 = Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row - 2
    
        For i = 1 To Lastrow2
        
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "          Total Rental Income" Then
        Range("B" & i, "M" & i).Copy
        TargetWb.Sheets("T-12 Drop").Range("E" & 4 + (k - 1) * 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
            End If
            
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "        Total Other Income" Then
        Range("B" & i, "M" & i).Copy
        TargetWb.Sheets("T-12 Drop").Range("E" & 5 + (k - 1) * 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
           End If

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "      Total Operating Expenses" Then
        Range("B" & i, "M" & i).Copy
        TargetWb.Sheets("T-12 Drop").Range("E" & 9 + (k - 1) * 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
           End If
              
        Next
    SourceWb.Close
        Next

 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Import").Activate

    MsgBox "All done!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Application.Trim` (which is just the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Trim`) on the cell's value:

```vb
If Application.Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "Total Rental Income" Then
```

and similarly for the other extract values.

---

Side Notes:

- The blanket `On Error Resume Next` is just hiding potential errors. Best practice would be to avoid using that.
- `Application.Trim` and just `Trim` or `Trim$` behave slightly differently. `Application.Trim` will remove spaces between words, while `Trim` or `Trim$` will only remove leading or trailing spaces on the entire string. Whether you use one or the other is down to preference and your data.

```vb
Debug.Print Application.Trim("  Total   Rental   Income ") '<~ returns "Total Rental Income"
Debug.Print Trim$("  Total   Rental   Income ")    '<~ returns "Total   Rental   Income"
```